# First coordinate of a line (x0,y0) doesn't affect starting position in SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, attributes, line

I'm drawing a line in my SVG component as shown in [this blog](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-basic-shapes-and-d3js).

```
svg.append("line")
  .attr({ x0: 300, y0: 100, x1: 340, y1: 200 })
  .attr({ "stroke": "blue", "stroke-width": "1" });
```

The line appears but only the second coordinate (x1,y1) affects its appearance. The first one (x0,y0) seems to have no effect and the line starts at origin.

I've tried adding more lines hoping that the second would at least start from the end of the previous but that's not it. (I'm not looking for a polyline - I was just trying to trouble-shoot the issue.) I've tried to switch back to the syntax with one attribute per method. No luck there neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've said

> The first one (x0,y0) seems to have no effect and the line starts at origin.

has no effect because of your SVG line attribute declaration

```
 <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="340" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
```

so line starts with ***x1*** & **y1** not **x0** & **y0** and ends with ***x2, y2***

hope that was what you were looking for.

Comment: So... Ducking... Stupid...   (typo intended - ducks are awesome!) I suspect it's time to hug the pillow...

Answer (score 2):

In SVG lines go from x1, y1 to x2, y2, there's no such thing as x0, y0

```js
svg = d3.selectAll("svg");

svg.append("line")
  .attr({ x1: 300, y1: 100, x2: 340, y2: 200 })
  .attr({ "stroke": "blue", "stroke-width": "1" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
```